# SDL don't load/show the right image

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-image

I'm writing a simple game. I'm stock by a bug that i can't figure out what are the causes.
In the code i write this:

```
DxFrame[0] = ImageLoader("Rome/Ball_Dx/RomeDx1.png");
DxFrame[1] = ImageLoader("Rome/Ball_Dx/RomeDx2.png");
DxFrame[2] = ImageLoader("Rome/Ball_Dx/RomeDx3.png");
DxFrame[3] = ImageLoader("Rome/Ball_Dx/RomeDx4.png");
DxFrame[4] = ImageLoader("Rome/Ball_Dx/RomeDx5.png");

SxFrame[0] = ImageLoader("Rome/Ball_Sx/RomeSx1.png");
SxFrame[1] = ImageLoader("Rome/Ball_Sx/RomeSx2.png");
SxFrame[2] = ImageLoader("Rome/Ball_Sx/RomeSx3.png");
SxFrame[3] = ImageLoader("Rome/Ball_Sx/RomeSx4.png");
SxFrame[4] = ImageLoader("Rome/Ball_Sx/RomeSx5.png");
```

But when I compile in the monitor DxFrame[4] is not what is should be. In fact he became SxFrame[0]. I can't understand why this happen.

Edit
This is the image loader:

```
        SDL_Surface* ImageLoader(string Image) {

        SDL_Surface* LoadedImage    = NULL;

        SDL_Surface* OptimizedImage = NULL;

        LoadedImage = IMG_Load(Image.c_str());

        OptimizedImage = SDL_DisplayFormat(LoadedImage);

        SDL_FreeSurface(LoadedImage);

        return OptimizedImage;
        }
```

I don't think there is nomore relevant code.

Comment: Please be more specific and post some relevant code, no one will read your entire source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arrays can hold 4 images but you are writing 5 in to them which will overwrite whatever comes after it.